# Open Chrome with ADB

Tags: android, adb

I used to able to launch Chrome using ADB like this:

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.android.chrome.Main
```

But now when I try it, I get:

```
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.android.chrome/.Main }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.android.chrome/com.android.chrome.Main} does not exist.
```

It seems that the Main Class name has changed. If so, what's the new one?

Comment: this works fine for me. `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://www.stackoverflow.com`

Comment: If you have more than one browser installed, it will ask you which one to use. I want to target Chrome specifically.

Comment: no if you set default to Chrome

Comment: Correct, but as I mentioned, I want to target Chrome specifically. As I do, for example, with Firefox but doing 'adb shell am start -n org.mozilla.fennec/org.mozilla.fennec.App'

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Adb command for this

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main
```

Comment: use `shell help`

Answer (score 4):

To open the default page of Chrome with ADB you can use:

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main
```

Instead, to open an url directly you can use:

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main -d "www.facebook.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
adb shell
```

webview with default browser:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d https://www.google.com/
```

**Firefox:**

```
monkey -p org.mozilla.tv.firefox -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
```

**Chromium:**

```
monkey -p org.chromium.chrome -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
```