# I need a command to open chrome on android from command line in selenium

Tags: android, selenium

I need a command to open chrome on android from the command line
I was thinking something like this :
adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.ChromeTabbedActivity -d "https://www.youtube.com/"
[image]
--activity-clear-task

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open Chrome with ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150650/open-chrome-with-adb)

Answer (score 0):

you can try ..
adb shell am start -n
com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity -d "about:newtab" -
-activity-clear-task